# Create View through Link server "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i want to create view trough link server to oracle DB."T.Test1" oracle db and "T2.dbo.tabel" sql db and ABC is link server.

```
exec
('CREATE VIEW T.TEST1 (value,Description) as

(select value,Description from T2.dbo.tabel);

') at ABC;
go
```

Comment: i am using link server from sql to oracle and want to create view using sql server management.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semi-colon, here:

```
 T2.dbo.tabel);
              ^
              |
```

---

Without parenthesis and semi-colon?

```
exec
('CREATE VIEW T.TEST1 (value,Description) as
 select value,Description from T2.dbo.tabel;
') at ABC;
go
```

---

One more attempt:

```
exec
('CREATE VIEW T.TEST1 as
 select value, Description from T2.dbo.tabel
') at ABC;
go
```

Comment: Hm. How about removing parenthesis AND semi-colon? See an example. Also, sorry for trying to help in such a futile manner; I don't know MS SQL Server.

Comment: Without parenthesis and semi-colon?  returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Comment: One more attempt; Have a look, please. It would certainly be better if there's someone who actually *knows* it; though, as it is Saturday and not many people ar online, I'm trying to assist.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using LINKED SERVERS in SQL Server, take this in consideration:

- You need to use the syntax: **[linkedserver].database.schema.table**
- You don't have to put semicolon
- You are using parenthesis in places you don't have to.

I would try:

```
exec (
'
CREATE VIEW T.TEST1 (value,Description) as select value,Description from [ABC].T2.dbo.table 
'
) at ABC
go
```

It should work like this, if ABC is the name of the LINKED SERVER.

This is an example that works:

```
EXECUTE  (
'
CREATE TABLE NAMESANDBIRTHDATES(
First_Name varchar2(50)
,Last_Name VARCHAR2(50)
,Birth_Date DATE)
'
)
at OrclDB
```

Comment: OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ABC" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended". i have already create table using above statement but facing difficulties to create view.

Comment: can you try to create a view in Oracle using a table in Oracle instead ? If so, the problem is related with something in the configuration and not in the setup

Comment: do you have HS configured in your Oracle database ?